# Change background url(img) based on prompt

Tags: javascript, background, prompt

I have:

```
var img = prompt("Enter your background url here");
```

then I add :

```
var img = prompt("Enter your background url here");
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(img)"; //img is a var
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: `img` is a variable you can't include it directly inside a string in JS. It should be like this `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";`

Comment: change "url(img)" to "url("+img"+)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate `img` properly.

```js
var img = prompt("Enter your background url here");
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+img+"')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var img = prompt("Enter your background url here");
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `img` is a variable, you need to concat it with `url`

```js
var img = prompt("Enter your background url here");
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+image+")";
```